# Unable to generate a pdf on Fedora 35 (pdfTex error: "cannot open Type 1 font file for reading")

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, texmaker, linuxfedora

I am unable to generate a pdf using Texmaker on Fedora 35.

For those familiar with Fedora, I installed TexLive then texmaker using:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full
sudo dnf install texmaker
```

These are all the Latex related Fedora packages I installed, but doing that was working fine out of the box on Fedora 34. Note that "texlive-scheme-full" is supposed to be the all-inclusive package for TexLive on Fedora.

I get no error on Texmaker when using Quick Build, there's just no pdf output. The log file is very long but the last line reads :

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file msbm10.t3): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
==> Fatal error occured, no output PDF file produced!
```

Here is an example of a document that doesn't produce a pdf output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
$\hbar$
\end{document}
```

Given what the log reads, I suspect I am missing a font used for some mathematical symbols. I am unfortunately completely ignorant about fonts. Should I just find out how to install a font called msbm10?

One of the common answers to similar questions on this website is to install TexLive directly from tug, but I was hoping to understand a little bit better what is happening here, and hopefully improve my knowledge about fonts.

Comment: It  would be more helpful to post a complete document that gives the error, unless you mean just adding `\begin{document}\end{document}` to the code shown gives the error?  first check if you have the file which should be `<tex-root>/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb` where `<tex-root>` is the root of where texlive files are installed. If it is there pdftex's file paths are wrong, if it is not there, the install failed to install it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have updated my question with a full document which gives the error.
Using  `sudo find -name msbm10.pfb` returns `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb` so given what you're saying, the problem is linked to pdftex's file paths. How can I check that?

Comment: you could try `sudo updmap-sys` to update pdftex's map files (the install should have done that) I don't actually have a linux packaged texlive to hand though so if that doesn't work I'll leave it for someone else to answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : `sudo updmap-sys` worked, thanks a lot! Maybe you can post your comment as an actual answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: David's reply did not work on my end. I am still getting the same error, but was also given a cascade of errors that are of the type paste below. Is this a reinstall tex-live issue (for which I don't know how to Fedora) or something else? updmap [WARNING]: Alegreya.map (from /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg) (used)
updmap [WARNING]: font AlegreyaSans-ThinItalic-osf-ts1--base is defined multiple times:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font file itself (`msbm10.pfb`) was apparently installed but (for some reason) the installation procedure failed to update the font map so that pdftex knew the font was there.

Running

```
sudo updmap-sys
```

runs the standard texlive map-updating utility, which you can do by hand if the dnf installation failed to run this.

Comment: This is a bug in the new Fedora 35 tex installation/update.  David C. solved it for us.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solutions did not work for me. I am still faced with the exact same problem as described in the original question. For testing, I am currently using a fresh Fedora 35 installation (using VirtualBox) and installed the texlive-scheme-full package.  Any other ideas to try?

Comment: While the fix of @DavidCarlisle was working for me 10 days ago, I now get the error `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file msam10.t3): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading`.  Running `updmap-sys` doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: `.t3` ? not an extension I reconnise @MátéWierdl

Comment: Notice that in the original post the same extension `t3` appears in the error message. There must be a typo somewhere.  I do not know how to present here, in the comments section, a minimal document, but the error appears if I use a character from the `amssymb` package.  Here is the minimal document

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\therefore$
\end{document}
`

Comment: The end of the run of pdflatex is `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/up
dmap/pdftex.map): fontmap entry for `rtxptmro' already exists, duplicates ignor
ed
}] (./t1test.aux) ){/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rep-cmr
m.enc}</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file msam10.t3): cannot open Type 1 font file for read
ing
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
`

Comment: When I grep for the .t3 extension in the `pdftex.map` file, I get many hits.  For example `xipxss10 xipxss10 <xipxss10.t3`

Comment: @MátéWierdl just proving there is some things that I don't really know about:-)  If you just ping here in comments it basically just goes to me, you would be better asking a new question if you have new data,

Comment: Well, I didn't know what to do, but I'll do what you suggest (I already reported the issue for Fedora 35.)  The t3 extension seems to be legitimate: denote type3 fonts.  I do have those files, like `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type3/mpfonts/xxfrak.t3`

Comment: @MátéWierdl It looks as if someone added mpfonts.map to updmap, something one shouldn't do as pdflatex obviously errors, see also https://ctan.org/pkg/mpfonts. You could try in your document `\pdfmapfile{-mpfonts.map}` to remove it again.

Comment: This works @UlrikeFischer!!! Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is sort of an answer only: when I install the original Texlive from CTAN (so not the Fedora 35 version) on my Fedora 35 system, all works well.  Also, it all works on an all updated Fedora 34. The issue is definitely with Fedora 35's texlive distribution.

Comment: I add that on a Fedora system which I upgraded from 34 to 35, the bug is not present anymore.  Apparenly the bugfix didn't make it into updates.